# How to call a function within the same module?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, requirejs

I'm trying to get my head round RequireJS in order to tidy up my app.

I have a few modules, and a main.js script.

In my main.js, I am defining a module that contains a few AJAX functions, to make basic API calls.

Inside this "API" module, I am first calling one of the AJAX functions, which after completion, needs to call a different AJAX function, inside the same "API" module (as these are Async tasks, I thought chaining them like this would be OK?!).

But, just calling the function name within the same module doesn't work.

So how do I call a function within the same module?

Here is how my "API" module is set out:

```
define(function() {
    return {
        ajaxCall_A: function() {
            $.ajax({
                // settings
            }).done(function() {
                // now call ajaxCall_B
                ajaxCall_B(); // doesn't work!
            });
        },
        ajaxCall_B: function() {
            $.ajax({
                // settings
            }).done(function() {
                // finished
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following change of adding a reference to the local object to the ajaxCall_A will fix the issue, however you'd probably be better off looking into [JQuery promises/deferreds](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) as this is a much nicer way of chaining Ajax calls.

```
define(function() {
    return {
        ajaxCall_A: function() {
            var self = this;
            $.ajax({
                // settings
            }).done(function() {
                // now call ajaxCall_B
                self.ajaxCall_B(); // doesn't work!
            });
        },
        ajaxCall_B: function() {
            $.ajax({
                // settings
            }).done(function() {
                // finished
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Brief example using promises (untested):

```
define(function() {
        return {
            ajaxCall: function() {
                $.when(this.ajaxCall_A())
                 .then(this.ajaxCall_B())
                 .done(function() {
                    // finished
                 });
            },
            ajaxCall_A: function() {
                return $.ajax({
                    // settings
                });
            },
            ajaxCall_B: function() {
                return $.ajax({
                    // settings
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Excellent, this works. Question - how difficult is it to combine jQuery Promises into RequireJS?

Comment: They will already work as you're using jQuery already. I'll add an untested example

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. Might be a quick one to answer, but is I have a module that simply has name pairs for global variables, how do I got about updating a variable? e.g. If I want to track a unique ID number throughout the application?

Comment: You'd probably have to wrap an object that maintains a closure reference to the uniqueId variable, so the contents of your define function would be: var uniqueId = 0; return{ getUniqueId: function() { return uniqueId; } }

Comment: I just had to do module_name.variable = "blah". for whatever reason, it didn't work before (most probably I typed it wrong ha!)

Comment: You may find issues where the value of module_name.variable differs when module_name is referenced in different places with this approach.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93590/discussion-between-mr-pablo-and-rob-willis).

Answer (score -1):

```
    (function (define) {
    return {
        ajaxCall_A: function () {
            $.ajax({
                // settings
            }).done(function () {
                // now call ajaxCall_B
                define.ajaxCall_B(); // it works now!
            });
        },
        ajaxCall_B: function () {
            $.ajax({
                // settings
            }).done(function () {
                // finished
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Try using like this.