# RequireJS - calling functions within the same file

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm trying to call a function as a callback from another function within the same file.

Code below, shows no errors, but does nothing - is there a different/better way to do this?

I'm calling first function from require config file (require-main.js) and that works fine

```
define(['require-main'], function() {
    require(['getJSON'], function(getJSON) {
        getJSON.stations();
    });
});
```

getJSON.js

```
define(['jquery', 'domChange', 'setUp'], function($, domChange, setUp) {
    var self = this;
    return {

        stations: function() {    
            $.get('/js/ajax/stations.json', function(sol) { /* local JSON */
                tmv.stations = sol;
                console.log(sol); /* this is fine */
                self.lines; /* <-- call next function */
            });
        },

        lines: function() {
            console.log('foo'); /* NOT called */
            $.get('/js/ajax/lines.json', function(lines) { /* local JSON */
                /* do something */
            });
        }
    }
});
```

[I've seen this question but I can't work this way as the order is not predetermined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33390448/how-to-call-a-function-within-the-same-module)

Update: as above, tried caching `this` into var but still no joy

Comment: `this.lines` this is the reference of the function, you are not actually calling it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this for the contents of your **getJSON.js**:

```
define(['jquery', 'domChange', 'setUp'], function($, domChange, setUp) {
    var getJSON = {

        stations: function() {    
            $.get('/js/ajax/stations.json', function(sol) { /* local JSON */
                tmv.stations = sol;
                console.log(sol); /* this is fine */
                getJSON.lines(); /* <-- call next function */
            });
        },

        lines: function() {
            console.log('foo'); /* NOT called */
            $.get('/js/ajax/lines.json', function(lines) { /* local JSON */
                /* do something */
            });
        }
    }
    return getJSON;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be

`tmv.stations = sol;
console.log(sol); /* this is fine */
this.lines(); /* <-- Actually calls the function */`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should keep the reference to **this** keyword before calling the ajax function

```
stations: function() {    
        var self = this;
        $.get('/js/ajax/stations.json', function(sol) { /* local JSON */
            tmv.stations = sol;
            console.log(sol); /* this is fine */
            self.lines(); /* <-- call next function */
        });
 }
```

Comment: he already does, and anyway this refer to the object in that case, not to the function

Comment: @Francescoes. BTW his var self = this is not at the same placed, I think my solution should work.